# Retrieve highest value per n rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where each row contains a value and a datetime. It has hundreds of thousands of rows. I would like to select the highest (max) value *every n rows*.

I had previously used a query to get the highest value every hour, but this isn't quite what I am looking for:

```
SELECT datetime, MAX(value)
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d &h')
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how would you specify `for every n rows`? is it based on datetime or some other criteria?

Comment: The rows are ordered by datetime and are indexed. So I'd want to retrieve the highest value in the first 100 values, then the highest value in the second 100 rows and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows and then aggregate to your heart's desire:

```
select min(rn), max(rn), min(datetime), max(datetime), max(value)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) rn
      from `table` t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by datetime
     ) t
group by floor((rn - 1) / @n)
order by min(rn);
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was after. Thank you!